# Use of SimpleJdbcCall to call stored procedure not using the current schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to use Spring JDBC Template to call a stored procedure inside a postgres database.
The connection is done from the yaml configuration file to indicate the current schema to use:

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5455/userdb?currentSchema=customschema`

Every queries done directly from jdbc template is using the correct current schema "customschema".
However, only executions done from SimpleJdbcCall to call a stored procedure is done in postgres default schema which is "public", and I can't understand why.

Here is the execution code:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("custom_stored_procedure_name").execute();
```

While debugging, if I look at that `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getSchema()`, it returns the correct schema which is "customschema".

I need to force the schema with `.withSchemaName("customschema")` for this execution to work with the correct schema instead of "public".

I can't find any documentation online regarding this behavior.

Is it an issue from the library itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Either specify the schema for each call or add the schema to the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).